# How can I prevent people from pasting formatted text?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, rich-text, style

Is there a way to prevent people from pasting formatted text into the rich text editor? I need to make sure only our approved styles are used.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this by modifying the master page and adding a little bit of JavaScript.

Rich Text Editor support pasting `Rich Text as-is` as well as `Plain Text`. In your case you need to enable the `Plain Text` mode.

For that first get the available modes

```
RTE.RtePasteManager.get_pasteModes()
```

And set the `Plain Text` mode

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/configuring-sharepoint-2010-rich-text-editor-paste-plaintext-only/

Comment: That's for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: @matt the same concept you can use in 2013. Read the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Add [this piece of JavaScript](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/configuring-sharepoint-2010-rich-text-editor-paste-plaintext-only/#li-comment-355307) (see Amal's answer) somewhere on the site:

```
$('[contenteditable]').attr('DefaultPasteModeResolver', 'PasteClean');
```

Then hide the pasting options from the ribbon and the flyout with CSS:

```
#rtePasteFlyoutOptions #rtePasteFlyoutOption0,
#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPEditTab\.Clipboard\.Paste\.Menu li:first-child  {
    display: none;
}
```